# Row and column headers in matplotlib's subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

What's the best practise to add a row and a column header to a grid of subplots generated in a loop in `matplotlib`? I can think of a couple, but not particularly neat:

1. For columns, with a counter to your loop you can use `set_title()` for the first row only. For rows this doesn't work. You would have to draw `text` outside of the plots.
2. You add an extra row of subplots on top and an extra column of subplots on the left, and draw text in the middle of that subplot.

Can you suggest a better alternative?

[image]

Comment: This should be easier to do.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  The easy way is to exploit the y-labels and titles of the plot and then use `fig.tight_layout()` to make room for the labels.  Alternatively, you can place additional text in the right location with [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) and then make room for it semi-manually.

---

If you don't have y-labels on your axes, it's easy to exploit the title and y-label of the first row and column of axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['Column {}'.format(col) for col in range(1, 4)]
rows = ['Row {}'.format(row) for row in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 8))

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.set_title(col)

for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.set_ylabel(row, rotation=0, size='large')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you do have y-labels, or if you prefer a bit more flexibility, you can use `annotate` to place the labels.  This is more complicated, but allows you to have individual plot titles, ylabels, etc in addition to the row and column labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy


cols = ['Column {}'.format(col) for col in range(1, 4)]
rows = ['Row {}'.format(row) for row in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 8))
plt.setp(axes.flat, xlabel='X-label', ylabel='Y-label')

pad = 5 # in points

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.annotate(col, xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.annotate(row, xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad - pad, 0),
                xycoords=ax.yaxis.label, textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='right', va='center')

fig.tight_layout()
# tight_layout doesn't take these labels into account. We'll need 
# to make some room. These numbers are are manually tweaked. 
# You could automatically calculate them, but it's a pain.
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, top=0.95)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The methods `is_first_col()`, `is_last_col()`, `is_first_row()` and `is_last_row()` may also be convenient in this context.

Comment: Also as a note, annotate matplotlib does have the rotate option, so if you want to rotate your label 90 degrees, just add the argument `rotation = 90`

Comment: Excuse me, what does the number 8 in figsize = (12, 8) do?

Comment: @Amirhosein The 8 is the height of the figure in inches and the 12 is the width, so (12,8) ensures a 4x3 aspect ratio. Because there are 3x3 subplots, this results in a sensible layout of landscape subplots.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Joe [Kington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25814386/13636407), I put up a function that can be reused across a code base:

It accepts as arguments:

- `fig` : The figure which contains the axes to work on
- `row_headers`, `col_headers` : a sequence of strings to be headers
- `row_pad`, `col_pad`: `int` value to adjust padding
- `rotate_row_headers`: whether to rotate by 90° the row headers
- `**text_kwargs`: forwarded to `ax.annotate(...)`

Function here, examples below:

```py
import numpy as np

def add_headers(
    fig,
    *,
    row_headers=None,
    col_headers=None,
    row_pad=1,
    col_pad=5,
    rotate_row_headers=True,
    **text_kwargs
):
    # Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25814386

    axes = fig.get_axes()

    for ax in axes:
        sbs = ax.get_subplotspec()

        # Putting headers on cols
        if (col_headers is not None) and sbs.is_first_row():
            ax.annotate(
                col_headers[sbs.colspan.start],
                xy=(0.5, 1),
                xytext=(0, col_pad),
                xycoords="axes fraction",
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha="center",
                va="baseline",
                **text_kwargs,
            )

        # Putting headers on rows
        if (row_headers is not None) and sbs.is_first_col():
            ax.annotate(
                row_headers[sbs.rowspan.start],
                xy=(0, 0.5),
                xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad - row_pad, 0),
                xycoords=ax.yaxis.label,
                textcoords="offset points",
                ha="right",
                va="center",
                rotation=rotate_row_headers * 90,
                **text_kwargs,
            )
```

Here is an example of using it using on a standard grid (no axes spans multiple rows / cols):

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mosaic = [
    ["A0", "A1", "A2"],
    ["B0", "B1", "B2"],
]
row_headers = ["Row A", "Row B"]
col_headers = ["Col 0", "Col 1", "Col 2"]

subplots_kwargs = dict(sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 6))
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, **subplots_kwargs)

font_kwargs = dict(fontfamily="monospace", fontweight="bold", fontsize="large")
add_headers(fig, col_headers=col_headers, row_headers=row_headers, **font_kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image: result: regular grid]

If some axes spans multiple rows / cols, it gets a bit less straightforward to assign rows / cols headers correctly.
I didn't managed to sort it out from inside the function, but being careful to the given `row_headers` and `col_headers` arguments is enough to make it work easily:

```py
mosaic = [
    ["A0", "A1", "A1", "A2"],
    ["A0", "A1", "A1", "A2"],
    ["B0", "B1", "B1", "B2"],
]

row_headers = ["A", "A", "B"]  # or
row_headers = ["A", None, "B"]  # or
row_headers = {0: "A", 2: "B"}

col_headers = ["0", "1", "1", "2"]  # or
col_headers = ["0", "1", None, "2"]  # or
col_headers = {0: "0", 1: "1", 3: "2"}

fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, **subplots_kwargs)
add_headers(fig, col_headers=col_headers, row_headers=row_headers, **font_kwargs)
plt.show()
```

[image: result: non-regular grid]

Answer (score 3):

The above answer works. Just not that in the second version of the answer, you have:

```
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.annotate(col, xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad-pad,0),
                xycoords=ax.yaxis.label, textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='right', va='center')
```

instead of:

```
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.annotate(row,xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad-pad,0),                    
                xycoords=ax.yaxis.label, textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='right', va='center')
```

Comment: This answer is in fact a comment about the accepted answer. The accepted answer seems to have been fixed accordingly. This answer could now be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As a extension of Joe's answer, you can use the Y-label approach, even with existing Y-labels, which I find much easier than using `annotate`, especially if the axes are not on a regular grid.

For this you can [twin](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) the axis and move it to the left:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,
                         sharex=True, sharey=True)

cols = [1, 2, 3]
rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']

# set existing Y label
axes[0][0].set_ylabel('Y label')

for c, ax in zip(cols, axes[0]):
    ax.set_title(c, size='large')

for r, ax in zip(rows, axes[:, 0]):
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    # move extra axis to the left, with offset
    ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
    ax2.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', -0.4))
    # hide spine and ticks, set group label
    ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.set_yticks([])
    ax2.set_ylabel(r, rotation=0, size='large',
                   ha='right', va='center')
```

Or course, if you also have existing titles, you can do the same thing with the X-axis to add extra labels on the top.

Output:

[image: matplotlib row column titles]

Output on a non regular grid:

[image: matplotlib row columns titles non regular grid]