# Annotations disappear in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I found the following method for labeling rows and columns in a subplot from an answer to this question: [Row and column headers in matplotlib's subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812255/row-and-column-headers-in-matplotlibs-subplots/25814386#25814386). It works great - for an empty plot. As soon as I add data to any of the subplots, the labels for that row and column disappear. I tried the `annotate` solution for this as well, same problem. I can't figure out how to get these labels to not disappear. Anybody else have the same problem? Ideas for solutions? (Code below.)

(I am working in a Jupyter notebook (.ipynb). I thought that might be the problem, but I tested it with a regular script (.py) and it doesn't work either.)

Working code and output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['Column {}'.format(col) for col in range(1, 4)]
rows = ['Row {}'.format(row) for row in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 8))

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.set_title(col)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.set_ylabel(row, size='large')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Working subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd9EY.png)

Code that is not working, with output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['Column {}'.format(col) for col in range(1, 4)]
rows = ['Row {}'.format(row) for row in ['A','B','C','D']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 8))

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.set_title(col)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.set_ylabel(row, size='large')

plt.subplot(431)
plt.scatter([1],[7]) #sample data

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Broken subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOPNZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plt.subplot(431)` is creating one subplot on top of an already existing axes, so all customization made to that specific object is erased. You need to tell the `scatter` function to be applied on the axes you want the plot to be shown; you can use the [axes class](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib-axes) to this end:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['Column {}'.format(col) for col in range(1, 4)]
rows = ['Row {}'.format(row) for row in ['A','B','C','D']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 8))

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.set_title(col)
for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.set_ylabel(row, size='large')

axes[0,0].scatter([1],[7]) #sample data

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```